# Using Spring MVC with Google Guava AtomicLongMap

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, guava

I have Spring MVC application that allows to reserve time period for something.

User selects time interval and then starts to fill in some data (name, address and so on).
But there is max count of reservations on one time period.

So, when user selects time interval and starts to fill in data, some other user is able to do this faster and get last place for this time period.

To prevent this I would like atomic hashmap, that would contain number of users that try to reserve this time period right now.

So, my question is:

Is it a good idea to use Google Guava AtomicLongMap for this purpose? Is it a good practice to use Spring together with Google Guava?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring works fine with guava - its just another dependency.

Java has its own built-in atomic package as well http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html

I think the normal way to solve a problem like yours is to simply lock out one reservation when a user starts (although not sure of the exact requirements from you question).

Comment: Note that JDK doesn't have built-in `AtomicLongMap` which OP wants.